# How can i reduce the file size of the ViewPort3D xaml?

Tags: xaml, size, reduce, 3ds

I have a 3D max file for a shape. And i convert it to a 3ds file. Then convert it to a xaml file by Zam3D. But the file is too big to load, my computer is crashed by the exception "Output of Memory". What can i do to reduce the xaml file size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how large is you file? I am working with 3D model files having about 8 MB and are very detailed. The largest I imported successfully had 13.4 MB and the 29 MB-model crashed with the same exception you got but it was not well designed.

To convert 3ds into xaml I am using the Reader3ds of [Wpf-Graphics](http://wpf-graphics.com). You avoid the step to convert it twice (through zam3d). The Reader3ds is able to read even large files and you can comfortably use the elements. Next I'm not glad using zam3d, I expect zam3d to put more information to the file than needed. Even the geometry I get is not the same as it was before and lights are added I did not use.

To reduce your xaml you can also try to work with a ResourceDictionary to swap the information to another file and just use it when it's needed.

Hope this helps

Stef

Comment: Hi Stef, thank you very very much, i will try you way immediately.